# Git status says up-to-date with remote even though it's not

Tags: git, git-status

We have a Git repository hosted on a shared network drive that multiple co-workers access. I'll call this the "central repository". Employees clone this repository to their local machines, make changes, and then push changes back up.

We've noticed that if someone pushes a change to the central repository, other employees' local Git repositories don't indicate that they are out of sync. `git status` says

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But it's clearly not up-to-date. There are changes on the remote, but Git isn't sensing them. You can do a `git pull` and it immediately downloads the changes to your local repository even though it claimed it was already up-to-date.

Why is this happening? Is it because the central repository is hosted on a shared network drive? And maybe Git is for whatever reason not able to tell if it's out of sync? Using a GUI like [Tower](https://downloads.zdnet.com/product/2229-75330136/) doesn't make a difference either. Even hitting "Refresh" in the GUI does not make any indication that it's out of sync. Also, the local master branch is tracking `origin/master`.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to call `git fetch` to get updates from the remote repository to your local repository, but without changing your current branch position. After that, `git status` will show proper results.